# A question about the socle of an algebra.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, socle

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field K. Suppose $e$ is an idempotent such that $Ae$ is the direct sum of all indecomposable injective-projective left $A$-modules. Is that $soc(_AA) \in add(soc(Ae))$ holds?

Comment: What is "add()"?

Comment: @rschwieb For an $A$-module $M$, $add(M)$ consists of direct summands of  direct sum of finite $M$.

Comment: what does "direct sum of finite $M$" mean? Does it mean "direct sum of finitely many copies of $M$?"

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true. For example, an algebra need not have any projective-injective modules. Consider the path algebra of the quiver $1\to 2\leftarrow 3$. Then none of the projective modules is injective, hence $e=0$, but $soc(A)=3S_2$.

It is true for algebras of positive dominant dimension, i.e. if the algebra, considered as a left module over itself embeds into a projective-injective module. Then, since $\operatorname{soc}$ is a left exact functor, $\operatorname{soc}(A)\in\operatorname{add} \operatorname{soc}(I)\subseteq  \operatorname{add}\operatorname{soc}(Ae)$ for this projective-injective module $I$. This class of algebras for example contains Auslander algebras as well as selfinjective algebras.